# Remove a child after x amount of seconds? AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

I would like to remove a child x amount of seconds after it is created. How can I do this?

The child is created inside of a function.

Basically, something like this...

```
function makechild() {
    addChild(thechild);
    thechild.x=240;
    thechild.y=330;
    // what should go here? so it deletes after x seconds?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a one-time timer via flash.utils.setTimeout() like this:

```
setTimeout(dropChild,seconds*1000);
...
function dropChild():void {
    removeChild(thechild);
}
```

Comment: Yeah just as you posted I figured it out...I was trying the exact same thing, but I messed up with the function name (added an extra capital letter) :( Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

With Actionscript 2 you would use setInterval. However, the Actionscript 3 way is to use the Timer class, like so:

```
function makechild() {
    addChild(thechild);
    thechild.x=240;
    thechild.y=330;
    // add a timer to "thechild" that will trigger it to be deleted
    thechild.selfdestruct:Timer = new Timer(1000, 1); // 1 second
    thechild.selfdestruct.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, deleteobject);
    thechild.selfdestruct.start();
}

function deleteobject(event:TimerEvent):void {
    // delete the child object, below is one example
    this.parent.removeChildAt(0);
}
```

You can get lots more details on the Timer class from the Actionscript documentation. For more info about the Timer class vs. setInterval see this link:
http://blogs.adobe.com/pdehaan/2006/07/using_the_timer_class_in_actio.html